# How to connect multiple branches with mysql server

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working in a freelance project where the client wants to install an instance of the system in all three of his branches, its developed using c#.
any ideas on how should i connect those branches is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Use Centralized MySql Server

1. Host your Mysql server Somewhere (AWS,Azure,Or any other providers)
2. Allow remote connection to mysql. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)
3. Configure Your Winform application to Connect to that server

**Note:- When hosting Mysql on server make sure your server has static IP. or you have to change the IP in you application every time your server gets new IP.**